# Using a timer(ticks) in lua, each load will make it faster

Tags: lua, timer

```
ticks = 0
ticks = ticks + 1
if ticks % 300 == 0 then
--do A
        clearStackTimer()
    end
```

This is my timer code, every time it is reloaded, it will speed up the timer once, how can I solve it? Thank you so much!

how to fix it please

Comment: You mean each load of the program? So is the question on how to save and load persistent data? Also please tag carefully, neither xticks nor reload is appropriate.

Comment: What game/software your Lua script is designed for?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (what is `clearStackTimer`?), and please define what *load/reload* means in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The OP question is legit, I had the same issue with a game and the player speed. Upon every game reload the player speed would increment adding the speed default value to itself. After like 3, 4 reloads the player speed was going crazy.

My issue was using an Async Call to reload the level. Removing it solved the issue.

In this case maybe the issue is the variable being global?